# Neo4j Regexp Negation not working

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I try to detect neo4j nodes where a certain property does NOT match a given regexp:

```
MATCH (n:`GithubCommit`) WHERE NOT (n.commit_message =~ '(?i).*merge.*') RETURN n.commit_message
```

While some nodes are properly filtered, the result set also contains the following:

`Merge pull request #378 from [...] Merge Dev in Master`

Is this a problem with my Cypher Query or a general problem in Neo4j Regexp Filtering?

Comment: are there other conditions in your real query that might shortcut the regexp check? perhaps you can share an example-dataset somewhere?

Comment: I just tested this with community-2.1.4 and enterprise-2.2-M02 and everything worked correctly as expected, even with a commit message identical to the one above. So I'm guessing there is something specific about the dataset here. If you could create a failing example, with a couple of CREATE statements that make the nodes, followed by the MATCH that finds the wrong nodes, then it would be easier to see if there is a problem.

Comment: I've tried to recreate this programatically, as well, but wasn't able to produce the same result. Interestingly, after updating one of the falsely returned nodes via Cypher by setting the commit_message to the same value, this node no longer shows up in the result set of the regex query. I'll close the question as it is supposedly related to way I insert my nodes (neography batch operations in Ruby...)

Comment: I've also created a neo database from all the commits, pull requests and jira issues to answer questions.    what questions does your model answer if you dont mind me asking @tkowark